# Take user to my activity from the file manager or from other apps

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app there is an activity that can edit the text files. I want to open all the text files in this activity. I tried the below intent-filter but it does not work, when clicking on a text file file manager don't show my app in available app's list. my question is how can I program my app so it can be available for any text files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/note_it_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/note_it_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name=".Welcome_Act"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name=".EditorActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_editor">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg"/>
        <data android:host="*" />
        <data android:scheme="file"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DialogActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecureActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name=".IntroActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name=".FirstNoteActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_first_note">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".PermissionActivity"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CreditActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name=".PreferenceActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_preference">
    </activity>
</application>
```

In the above code EditorActivity can open and edit text file. I want to open text files from the storage using EditorActivity. I want to add my App's EditorActivity in below list show in screen shot.
[image: screen shot of available text editors]

Comment: It would be better if you include little bit more detail and code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

well, I was using android Nougat and it also need one more thing that is:

```
<data android:scheme="content" />
```

and now its working. the full Intent-filter is:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg"/>
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:scheme="content" />
</intent-filter>
```